# NGINX fails to load site

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a nginx site listening on port 8000. I have Apache listening on port 80.

When I try to load nginx site, this error is shown in the log:

```
2019/03/27 20:13:06 [alert] 7845#7845: 1024 worker_connections are not enough
2019/03/27 20:13:06 [error] 7845#7845: *17498 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: erp.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "erp.example.com"
```

And in browser default 502 page is shown, located at "/opt/bench/bench-repo/bench/config/templates" folder.

What may be wrong here?

This is the full nginx.conf file:

```
upstream erpnext-frappe {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream erpnext-socketio-server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}



# setup maps


# server blocks





server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name
        erp.example.com
        ;

    root /opt/bench/erpnext/sites;





    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    location /assets {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/protected/(.*) {
        internal;
        try_files /erp.example.com/$1 =404;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Frappe-Site-Name erp.example.com;
        proxy_set_header Origin $scheme://$http_host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://erpnext-socketio-server;
    }

    location / {
        try_files /erp.example.com/public/$uri @webserver;
    }

    location @webserver {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Frappe-Site-Name erp.example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Use-X-Accel-Redirect True;
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass  http://erpnext-frappe;
    }

    # error pages
    error_page 502 /502.html;
    location /502.html {
        root /opt/bench/bench-repo/bench/config/templates;
        internal;
    }

    # optimizations
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    client_max_body_size 50m;
    client_body_buffer_size 16K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;

    # enable gzip compresion
    # based on https://mattstauffer.co/blog/enabling-gzip-on-nginx-servers-including-laravel-forge
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/font-woff
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        ;
        # text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
}
```

I have compared with a virtual machine where this application is also installed and working and it is almost the same. The difference is that in that other machine, nginx is listening on port 80 and python on port 8000.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have changed location / configuration to:

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

That is, I removed proxy pass configuration and now nginx tried to load the site, but the error is "forbidden":

```
*23053 directory index of "/opt/bench/erpnext/sites/" is forbidden
```

How can I solve this in NGINX?

Comment: Why do you listen python and nginx with the same port 8000?

Comment: No.. you did not understand. The other PC, where NGINX works, NGINX is listening on port 80 and python on port 8000. My PC, where NGINX does not work, has Apache listening on port 80 and NGINX on port 8000. Furthermore, the config file was created automatically by bench installation script. I have only changed port 80 to port 8000

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @jstuardo the problem is you have too many variables — noone has 15 minutes just to read this question to make sense of all the unrelated servers on the identical ports.  It's almost the same?  Sounds like it almost works, so, what's the problem?!

Comment: @cnst I did not understand you. Are you asking me what the problem is? Is it not clear when I show the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it.

The solution was to set nginx to listen in another port, for example, 8020. Then I rebooted the server.

After reboot I checked that python started listening on port 8000 and nginx on port 8020.

That way it worked. I don't really know why python is listening on port 8000 and how it can be changed, but it doesn't matter now.

Regards
Jaime